# Expected token not found in attributes: ITunesSoftwareApplicationTestedOn40

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When trying to submit my Application using Application Loader i am getting the following error:

```
Expected token not found in attributes: ITunesSoftwareApplicationTestedOn40
```

[image]

Where can i set this attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same error message. I restarted the Application Loader, the package is now uploading. :)

Regards.

Comment: A system restart worked for me, didn't expect it to be such a simple bug to get around, isn't usually the case with Apple!